# How to produce a pivoted time-series table from an unpivoted flat file

Tags: python, time-series, flat-file

I have an unpivoted time-series flat file. 
It contains daily returns n factors over t number of days. 
In the past, the data was provided with an easy format to manipulate in Excel: factors across columns and dates in rows. However, the new "unpivoted" format is now in production and I need to find a solution so that I am able to chart time-series of factor returns.

The is the format of the source flat file: (only 3 columns).

```
factor_name   DailyReturn  Date
factor1         0.0212    yyyymmdd
factor2         0.0472    yyyymmdd
factor n
...
```

As part of my learning Python and given it is the choice of language in the firm... I would like to do this file manipulation in Python.

The output should be something along the lines of 
(the n

```
Date        factor1    factor 2  factor n...
yyyymmdd      0.0212   0.0472    -0.0408
etc
```

There should be about n columns and thousands of rows as the file goes back a long way. 
Then I should be able to import this into Excel or plot time series returns using Python.

Answer (score 0):

-Hey- Rabt. We could do this for you but as you are keen on learning it might be better to break this problem down and let you have a go first. From a pragmatic perspective the fastest way would be to load this file into excel and transpose in there. But coding is fun too!

First step is load the data, so google "python load file".

Second step is converting this flat file data into python data structures. I would use a dictionary of dictionaries. The other dictionary uses date as a key. Inner dictionary will use the factor name as the key and the value will be the daily return. As with most problems there are many ways, you could also use pandas here but maybe learn that later.

Loop through each line and split the string. Google "python split string".

Once you have split a line, search for the line's date in the outer dictionary. If it doesnt exist add a new entry with an internal dictionary: outerdict[date] = dict(). Then you can insert your factor into this internal dictionary. outerdict[date][factor] = dailyreturn.

Final step is outputting to CSV. You will want to use the csv package for this. Google "python csv". You will loop through all key and value in the outer dictionary, which will give you the date as the key. Google "python loop dictionary". The internal dictionary has your factors which you can also loop through with key being the factor name and value being the daily return.

What may get confusing is whether or not every date has all the factors and whether they are in different orders. Not sure, would have to look at your dataset to answer that.

I've put this here as an answer because it's way too much text to put in comments. But we can clean this up later if need be.

If you want to do more stuff in python with the loaded data just use the dictionaries we created.

Answer (score 0):

I got what I wanted by using .unstack() in pandas. 
This converts the 3-column dataframe into a standard n rows-dates, x columns-factors dataframe.